# is any record connected to anather

Tags: mysql

```
 TABLE A
 id=1
+file_id=100
|
| TABLE B
|id=1
+file_id=100
|
|TABLE FILES
>id=100
 file_name = picture.jpg
 file_size = 99999
```

file_id of TABLE A and TABLE B are in connection width TABLE FILES id.

I would like to check if **any of** the two table records are pointed to the file with let sey id=100. If not the file would be deleted.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the results of the query:

```
SELECT filename 
FROM files f
WHERE (
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A WHERE file_id= f.id) 
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE file_id = f.id)
)
```

This (ideally) gets the files which are not referenced in either A or B

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of ids that are not linked to by any of the two tables with this query:

```
SELECT f.id AS id FROM files f
LEFT JOIN a ON f.id = a.file_id
LEFT JOIN b ON f.id = b.file_id
WHERE a.id IS NULL AND b.id IS NULL
```

The idea is that you perform a left outer join to the `A` and `B` tables starting from table `FILES`; records in `FILES` that do not have a corresponding entry on the other tables (as specified by the `JOIN` condition) will have `NULL` values for all columns of these tables. Therefore, if a row has `NULL` for both `a.id` and `b.id` it means that there is no corresponding row in either of the `A`, `B` tables for the specific file.

Comment: And what if there is N piece of tables that can point to the file? I have to list all of them?

Comment: @2astalavista: If there are N tables then you are probably doing something wrong with your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
DELETE F
FROM files AS F
LEFT JOIN tablea AS A ON F.`id` = A.`file_id`
LEFT JOIN tableb AS B ON F.`id` = B.`file_id`
WHERE ISNULL(A.id) AND ISNULL(B.id);
```

(after posting this I've seen thats the same approach already used by Jon)